# Keep bootstrap nav ul elements from stacking for small screen sizes

Tags: twitter-bootstrap-3, nav

I'd like the two links which appear at the end of the nav to stay on the same line when I view the page on a xs screen size.

How do I do that? Here's a snippet of my code for the nav.

```
<div class="navbar navbar-inverse" style="margin-bottom: 0px;background-color:#f44336">
                <div class="navbar-header">
                    <button aria-controls="bs-navbar" aria-expanded="false"
                        class="collapsed navbar-toggle" style="float:left"
                        data-toggle="offcanvas" type="button">
                        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                    </button>
                    <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right" style="float:right">
                        <li>
                            <i class="zmdi zmdi-notifications zmdi-hc-lg zmdi-hc-fw"
                                style="color:white; padding-top: 10px;padding-right:32px"></i>
                        </li>
                        <li>
                            <i class="zmdi zmdi-account-circle zmdi-hc-lg zmdi-hc-fw"
                                style="color:white; padding-top: 10px;padding-right:32px"></i>
                        </li>
                    </ul>
                </div>
            </div>
```

Thanks,

Dan

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using display:inline on the li element solved the issue.